# implementation of put method in a hashmap

Tags: java

I was reading about maps in java. I did this code.

```
public class Test {

    private HashMap<String, Integer> h;
    private int dataCount;

    public Test() {

        h = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        dataCount = 0;
    }

    public String getNumber(String name) {

        for (String k : h.keySet()) {
            if (k.equals(name)) {
                Integer v = h.get(k);
                return k+" "+v;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void putNumber(String name, Integer number) {
        Iterator<String> i = h.keySet().iterator();
        if (i.equals(name)) {
            h.put(name, number);
        } 
        h.put(name, number);
        dataCount++;

    }

//  public void putNumber(String name, Integer number) {
//      
//      for (String k : h.keySet()) {
//          if(k.equals(name)) {
//              h.put(k, number);
//          } 
//              h.put(name, number);
//              dataCount++;
//          }
//  }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Test t = new Test();
        t.putNumber("ali", 123);
        t.putNumber("ala", 658);
        t.putNumber("baba", 987);
        t.putNumber("ali", 666);

        System.out.println(t.dataCount);
        System.out.println(t.getNumber("ali"));
        System.out.println(t.h);

    }

}
```

When I run this code I get :

```
4
ali 666
{baba=987, ala=658, ali=666}
```

It should not be like that, I want it to be like this :

```
3
{ali 666, baba=987, ala=658}
```

in my putNumber method when a name is already exisitng in the map so I just want to change its number and not add the same name again with a new number.

I have also that my second putNumber method with the for each loop does not nork at all. When I run the code with the putNumber method (for each one) I get this:

```
0
null
{}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your `putNumber` method is wrong, it should be something like

```
public void putNumber(String name, Integer number) {
    Iterator<String> i = h.keySet().iterator();
    if (i.equals(name)) {
        h.put(name, number);
    } else {
        h.put(name, number);
        dataCount++;
    }
}
```

Right now, if the key is already present, it will *still* increase the `dataCount`.

However, there's another problem with this code. One of the main advantages of using a `HashMap` is that you can look up the keys very fast; you *don't need* to iterate over the keyset, you can just use `h.containsKey(name)` and `h.get(name)`. Also, it has a built-in [size()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#size()) method with the same properties as your `dataCount`.

Comment: Actually, you are not iterating, you are using equals to compare an iterator to a string

Answer (score 4):

Your `putNumber` method contains multiple errors :

- `i.equals(name)` you're comparing a `String` with an `Iterator<String>`. That won't work
- if your condition was ever true, you would execute `h.put` twice (which isn't problematic, but clearly is useless)
- you would always execute `dataCount++` (when it should be the only thing conditioned)

Here's what I would do instead :

```
public void putNumber(String name, Integer number) {
    if (!h.containsKey(name)) {
        dataCount++;
    }
    h.put(name, number);
}
```

Alternatively, using an `HashTable` (where `null` isn't an authorized value) instead of an `HashMap` would make it possible to rely on the return value of `HashTable.put(key, value)` which will return `null` if there was no previous mapping for the `key` :

```
public void putNumber(String name, Integer number) {
    if (h.put(name, number) == null) {
        dataCount++;
    }
}
```

Also note that the `HashMap` class defines a `.size()` method which might make maintaining a `dataCount` variable useless.

Comment: Here  `if (h.put(name, number) == null)`
The condition is also `true` if the map previously associated `null` with the `name` key. So this code :  `t.putNumber("ali", 123); t.putNumber("ali", null); t.putNumber("ali", 1234); ` will have as dataCount `2` instead of `1`

Comment: You're right, it is even underlined in the JavaDoc. I must have been thinking about `Hashtable`s, where `null` aren't authorized neither as key or value

Comment: Indeed. With Hashtable the problem doesn't exist by definition. But I agree it's a beautiful line of code :)

Answer (score 2):

You are not using `HashMap` correctly.

There's no point in iterating over the `keySet` to locate a specific key. That's what `get`, `put` and `containsKey` are for.

```
public void putNumber(String name, Integer number) { 
    if (h.put(name, number) == null)
        dataCount++; // increment the counter only if the name was not already in the Map
}

public String getNumber(String name) {
    Integer v = h.get(name);
    return v == null ? null : name+" "+v;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public void putNumber(String name, Integer number) {
    Iterator<String> i = h.keySet().iterator();
    if (i.equals(name)) {
        h.put(name, number);
    } 
    h.put(name, number);
    dataCount++;
}
```

1) In any cases, you put the element in the map. So you should not repeat yourself.
2) Besides dataCount is incremented at each time even when no new value is added.
3)   `if (i.equals(name))` doesn't compare all keys but compare the iterator value with the name parameter.

Try that :

```
public void putNumber(String name, Integer number) {
     if (!h.containsKey(name)){
         dataCount++;    
     }
     h.put(name, number);               
 }
```

Besides, getNumber() could be also simplify since by using one more time the containsKey() method of the map.

```
public String getNumber(String name) {     
     if (h.containsKey(name)){
         Integer v = h.get(k);
         return k+" "+v;    
     }               
    return null;
}
```

Comment: While your analysis is correct, the suggested solution won't work. The order between the `datacount` increment and the `h.put` call should be reversed, or you'll always find the key you've just inserted.

Answer (score 0):

Your putNumber method makes little sense:

```
public void putNumber(String name, Integer number) {
    Iterator<String> i = h.keySet().iterator(); //i is an iterator
    //this returns always false, you are comparing an iterator to a string
    if (i.equals(name)) {
        h.put(name, number);
    }

    //this code is always executed
    h.put(name, number);
    dataCount++;
}
```

What you should do is something like:

```
public void putNumber(String name, Integer n) {
    h.put(name,n);
    dataCount=h.size();
}
```

Or, if you want something more "manual":

```
public void putNumber(String name, Integer n) {
    if (h.get(name)==null) {
        dataCount++;
    }
    h.put(name,n);
}
```